# Masonry goes to one column after hiding and showing divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, masonry

I looked around a bit but I couldn't find something that would fix my problem. Basically I have a masonry layout where each item is 25% wide, and they all fit on the same page. I have some buttons at the top which will show or hide items when the user clicks on them based on other data. So I have my masonry like this:

```
            $('.gallery-holder').masonry({
                itemSelector: '.gallery-item',
                isAnimated: true,
                isResizeBound: false
            }).imagesLoaded(function() {
                $('.gallery-holder').masonry('reloadItems');
            });
```

And when the user clicks on one of the options, this happens:

```
            $('.portfolio-header-holder h1').on('click', function() {


                if(!$(this).hasClass('current')) {
                    $('.portfolio-header-holder h1').removeClass('current')
                    var pclass = $(this).attr('class');

                    $(this).addClass('current')
                    $('.gallery-holder .gallery-item').show();

                    $('.gallery-holder .gallery-item:not(.'+pclass+')').hide();                     

                } else {
                    $(this).removeClass('current');
                    $('.gallery-holder .gallery-item').show();
                }

                $('.gallery-holder').masonry({
                    itemSelector: '.gallery-item',
                    isAnimated: true,
                });

            });
```

So I'm running the masonry function again to try and get everything to reorder and fit again. However when you click on one of the buttons, all the '.gallery-item's go into a single column. I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try using isotope with masonry layout. It works much better for filtering and it is made by the same guy  :)

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonry.html

Comment: I'd rather not since Isotope requires a license for commercial projects.

Comment: It's a measly 25 dollars for the commercial license. That's pretty bad if your budget can't handle that. You can also use in themes without any problem, the theme purchaser doesn't need to purchase a license unless they make another item for resale from it.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I figured it out, for anyone wondering you have to set columnWidth. For me since it was a reflexive columnWidth, I just set it to the class of the item like this:

```
columnWidth: '.gallery-item'
```